# Where can I find Bitcoin Misery Index?

Tags: trading, market-indexes, cryptocurrency, volatility

There has been a lot written about [Bitcoin Misery Index](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bitcoin-misery-index.asp):

> The index is called the Bitcoin Misery Index (BMI) and was designed as
>   a trading tool for investors to take advantage of volatility in BTC
>   exchanges. BMI is calculated on a scale of zero to 100, taking into
>   account factors such as volatility and the number of winning trades
>   out of the total. When the indicator is low, the buying opportunity is
>   at its best, and vice versa.

But all I find are just reviews; I cannot find the index itself! Is it somewhere freely available and updated?

Comment: OK! I didn't know such site exisits, thanks!

Comment: @Brythan hmm, it seems that the Bitcoin SE is mostly technical than about investments. I'd prefer to keep it here for some time and consider migration later if it gets no response here.

Comment: @Brythan Bitcoin.SE explicitly prohibits investing questions. Money.SE is the right site for this question.

Comment: @BenMiller Except that this is a product/service recommendation, and hence off-topic.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea It's not really a product/service recommendation, in my opinion.  This is an index that is discussed in the media (and Investopedia), and I think it is a valid question to ask where it can be seen.  If the only answer is "behind a paywall," then that is a great answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/chuckjones/2018/03/10/the-bitcoin-misery-index-bmi-is-flashing-a-buy-signal/#452ca94c6a22),

> Tom Lee, Fundstrat Global Advisors' head of research, introduced a Bitcoin Misery Index, or BMI, on Friday.

The [Fundstrat Website](https://www.fundstrat.com/firm/team/) includes Thomas Lee as its head of research. The index does not seem to be publicly available on the website. Without being a client myself, I can only speculate that the index is proprietary, but is available to paying clients.